# Where is DB.php is located?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have executed my php program which requires DB.php file. While executing the php program it showed the following 
error.

```
    Warning: require(DB.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or 
directory in /home/roja/public_html/form/BOOK/design.php on line 2

    Fatal error: require() [function.require]: 
Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
in /home/roja/public_html/form/BOOK/design.php on line 2
```

I don't know how to solve this issue. If anyone know about this issue please tell me the way to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're missing this? http://pear.php.net/package/DB

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I have installed DB in my home directory using pear install DB-1.7.14RC2. But it said the following warning. WARNING: "pear/DB" is deprecated in favor of "pear/MDB2"
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update pear.php.net" to update
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pear.php.net" is not writeable by the current user. After that also my php file displayed the same error only.

Comment: @rekha_sri Try sudoing the pear install, otherwise find out what the php_dir for channel "pear.php.net" is, and chmod it to give you write permissions